Connecting up the vintage Morse Code Instructograph
As a teenager (1950's) I used an original Instructograph to learn Morse Code for my ham licenses, and had obtained a speed of up to about 30 wpm.
Now 70 years later, I have obtained both 3-post and 4-post Instructographs to be connected up to recoup my code and reapply for a new Extra ham license. I would be very grateful if someone could please detail for me how to connect the batteries, headset and oscillator to both of these types (3-post and 4-post) Instructographs. The machines are the post-crank type with electric motors.

FYI, in the USA, Morse code is no longer required for any license class, not even Amateur Extra.

But it's even more heavily used than when it was required!

Looks like an interesting project. Wouldn't be easier to use one of the many internet apps for learning morse code? Take care.
